# Displaying results from search API

Tags: python, forms, web2py, blekko

I'm trying to get to grips with web2py/python. I want to get the user to fill in a search form, the term they search for is sent to my python script which should send the query to the blekko API and output the results to them in a new HTML page. I've implemented the following code but instead of my normal index page appearing, I'm getting the html response directly from blekko with '%(query)' /html appearing in it's search bar. Really need some help with this!

HTML form on the default/index.html page

```
<body>

<div id="MainArea">
  <p align="center">MY SEARCH ENGINE</p>
  <form name="form1" method="get" action="">
    <label for="SearchBar"></label>
    <div align="center">
      <input name="SearchBar" type="text" id="SearchBar" value="" size = "100px"><br />
      <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Search">
    </div>
  </form>
  <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
```

Python code on the default.py controller

```
import urllib2

def index():
    import urllib2


    address = "http://www.blekko.com/?q='%(query)'+/html&auth=<mykey>"
    query = request.vars.query

    response = urllib2.urlopen(address)

    html=response.read()
    return html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding how [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) works. You need to put the address and query together still:

```
address = "http://www.blekko.com/?q='%(query)s'+/html&auth=<mykey>" % dict(query=request.vars.query)
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn. That's the format of their API request URL it works perfectly if you replace '%(query' with your search term.

Comment: @adohertyd: I had a slight typo in there; I added the missing `s` and tested it for you on blekko.com. The address from my answer, minus the `auth` parameter, gives me results.

Comment: Ah, of course, the single quotes make the query work as a phrase; I added them back in.

Comment: That works now Martin thank you. The problem remains however that the blekko results page automatically appears when I go to the index. My HTML form doesn't appear so I don't have the option of actually putting in a search term!

Comment: @adohertyd: How did you display your form before? You'd need to see if `query` is defined and show your form if it isn't (`if not request.vars.query: # show form`).

Comment: The form displays without the python script. Is there a way to return the form value as a variable in the python script? i.e. create a variable in python called `query` that is populated by the value of the search field when submit is pressed? A form action or something?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13360/discussion-between-martijn-pieters-and-adohertyd)

Answer (score 1):

Add a hidden field to your form, call it "submitted". Then reformat your controller function as such:

```
import urllib2

def index():
    if request.vars.submitted:
        address = "http://www.blekko.com/?q='%(query)'+/html&auth=<mykey>"
        query = request.vars.query
        response = urllib2.urlopen(address)
        html=response.read()
        return html
    else:
        return dict()
```

This will show your index page unless the form was submitted and the page received the "submitted" form variable.